# A particular isomorphism between Hom and first Ext.

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $R$ commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

How do I prove that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(R/I,R/I)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_R(I/I^2,R/I)$ ?

This question is an exercise of the course but has a chance of being false.

Comment: Have you tried playing with some basic examples first, $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I=p\mathbb Z$ for some prime $p$? I have no idea how to attack such problem, but in my experience trying to see how the basic problems work can give you quite some insight for later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really only one thing you can try when confronted with such a problem: find a suitable short exact sequence. Here's an obvious one:
$$0 \to I \to R \to R/I \to 0$$
Applying $\textrm{Ext}_R^\bullet$, we get
$$0 \to \textrm{Hom}_R(R/I, R/I) \to \textrm{Hom}_R(R, R/I) \to \textrm{Hom}_R(I, R/I) \to \textrm{Ext}_R^1(R/I, R/I) \to 0$$
since $R$ is a projective $R$-module. Now, observe that $\textrm{Hom}_R(R, R/I) \cong R/I$ by the universal property of $R$ as a free $R$-module, while $\textrm{Hom}_R(I, R/I) \cong \textrm{Hom}_R(I/I^2, R/I)$ by considering the action of any element in $I$. On the other hand, the map $\textrm{Hom}_R(R, R/I) \to \textrm{Hom}_R(I, R/I)$ must be the zero map. Hence,
$$\textrm{Hom}(I/I^2, R/I) \cong \textrm{Ext}_R^1(R/I, R/I)$$
as required.